# Installing Ruby 1.8.7 on Intel MacOSX 10.5.8 - error with make

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm

I am having problems with installing Ruby 1.8.7 using RVM on my Intel architecture MacOSX 10.5.8.

- It configures & compiles properly but gives me errors during making.
- I tried searching this out but am unable to get through to a solution.
- My RVM is installed as single user

Links to my make.log files & my action trails can be found on this springpad note: http://sprng.me/c1s9k

> I am assuming that it has got to do with my Developer tools & Xcode(version 3.1.2). I am clueless at the same time though and will appreciate any kickstart you can give me in solving this. I am keen on starting to develop my RoR apps! :D

Comment: Sorry, just deleted my answer, as looking through those links Xcode is correctly installed. This looks to be an issue with RVM. Not the answer what you're looking for, but I ditched RVM in favour of rbenv + ruby-build, and many others are making the same decision.

Comment: Actually untrue, many others are NOT making the same decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RVM currently requires Xcode version 3.2.1 at the least. Don't go over version 4.1 though. 4.2 has some serious issues with building rubies and gems, and some of the homebrew and macports packages. They're using an llvm-gcc which is breaking a lot of things.

As for your issue here. Are you running on a 64bit machine? The error in the make logs appear to be based on the architecture type being incorrect. RVM defaults to a x86_64 architecture because the vast majority of the people using it are using 64bit machines, so RVM sets the default to that.We set this in scripts/functions/build and scripts/selector.

We also look for a variable called rvm_arch_flags where you can set the architecture flag needed for your model. This might not be an issue for you if you are using a Core 2 Duo or something similar. Are you running a PPC or something? We usually have issues awith people running Leopard because they are running the early Intels which appear to have been 32bit. You need at least the core 2 duo or xeon based machines.

Now, looking deeper into this, I would try setting rvm_arch_flag='-arch i686' in your global .rvmrc and try rebuilding. if you still run into problems come find me in the #RVM channel on freenode irc. We'll see what we can do. Please also create me a gist of rvm --trace  as well.

In addition, it appears to be having problems with the version of the Tcl/Tk frameworks that comes with your Xcode. This could also be due to it being 3.1 rather than 3.2.

Comment: I'm running on Leapord, which supports 3.1.4 max!

I uninstalled Xcode, downloaded 3.1.4 & re-installed 3.1.4.

The following is the make.log I now get for 1.8.7-p352: http://pastie.org/2837960

For 1.8.7-head, here it is: http://pastebin.com/1gBU5GF4

Comment: I also found this patch file at .rvm/patches/ruby/1.8.7/osx-arch-fix.patch. I have applied it & ruby installed flawlessly! Thanks to your input regarding rvm_arch_flags, I happened to explore the rvm folder to find the .rvmrc file, when I found this patch :)

Cheers!